# Refresh button values on page

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have such model

```
public class TutorialModel
    {
        public string TitleWord { get; set; }

        public List<string> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }

        public List<bool> Colors { get; set; }

    }
```

and Controller

```
public class TutorialController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Tutorial/
    private TutorialModel model = new TutorialModel();

    public ActionResult Index(TutorialModel paramModel)
    {
        model.TitleWord = "Go";
        model.Colors = new List<bool>();
        model.PossibleAnswers = new List<string>();
        model.PossibleAnswers.Add("1");
        model.PossibleAnswers.Add("2");
        model.PossibleAnswers.Add("3");
        model.PossibleAnswers.Add("4");

        return View(this.model);
    }
}
```

with view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Tutorial";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Tutorial"))
{
    <div id="progressTimer"></div>
    <br />
    <br />

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">@Model.TitleWord</button>
    <br />

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.PossibleAnswers.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" id="@Model.PossibleAnswers[i]" value="@Model.Colors[i]" onclick=" checkAnswer(this) " class="btn btn-default" >@Model.PossibleAnswers[i]</button>
        </div>
    }
}
<script>
    function checkAnswer(element) {
        if ($(element).val()) {
            $(element).css("background-color", "green");
        } else {
            $(element).css("background-color", "red");
        }
    }
</script>
```

My application is a small tutorial. And after I will press one of the buttons backgroung color of it changed and I need to refresh text and values on all buttons with js. Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

make sure the buttons have a unique class(.) or id(#)
 and use that as a selector.  you can change the button value like this

```
$('.btn-default').val('New Value');
```

if you want to set something different on the tag there are some prebuilt option (.text, etc).  For other options use .attr